# Syntax for converting code from MATLAB to PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert a snippet of code from  `MATLAB` to  `Python`. Could some one help me in converting the below line of code in `MATLAB` to `Python`

```
f = ifftshift( 1.0 ./ (1.0 + (radius ./ cutoff).^(2*n)) );
```

where variables 'radius' and 'cutoff' are two matrices.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `radius` and `cutoff` are vectors or scalar (i.e. MATLAB 1x1 vector) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `numpy` module for `ifftshift`,
and `**` instead of `^` (`^` in python is `xor`)

```
import numpy as np
np.fft.ifftshift(1.0 / (1.0 + (radius / cutoff) ** (2*n)))
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your quick response.